# Foreach loop correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, datatable

I have a data table and i'm trying to loop through the rows and create a zipCode array.  This issue that i'm only getting one number 4 times.  I know I'm doin something wrong but can somebody point this out to me and give and explanation.

Thanks

```
    public string bindMap()
{

    using (dal.Sys.RegionTableAdapters.region_countyListTa ta = new Cea.WebApp.JobsEq.Dal.Sys.RegionTableAdapters.region_countyListTa())
    {
        List<string> code = new List<string>();

        dal.Sys.Region.region_countyListDataTable dt = ta.GetData(region.RegionType, region.RegionCode);
        foreach (var row in dt)
        {                
            code.Add(region.ZipCode);                

        }//end foreach loop

        string codes = string.Join(",", code.ToArray());
        return codes.ToString();


    }//end for each loop        
}//end bind map
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't using the variable that you are iterating with.

```
   foreach (var row in dt)
    {                
        //Not sure how you will get ZipCode from the ROW, but you get the idea. 
        code.Add(row["ZipCode"]);                

    }//end foreach loop
```

Comment: +1 Unless... here me out here... _iterating_ a `dal.Sys.Region.region_countyListDataTable` has side effects whereby the `region.ZipCode` gets updated. [Alternatively...](http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1719734609/ancient-aliens-guy.png)

Comment: Thanks changed it around and found out had some other issues going on but this worked

Answer (score 0):

As a general desc of the row/cell value, I use this general (NOTE: GENERAL) block:

```
foreach(var item : items) {
//before adding there is maybe some casting or other work...
    listName.add(item["FieldName"]);
}
```

Understandable is that the listName is of type fieldNameType